# How to define this search?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have customer codes stored in a table. Customer codes are stored as:

```
CSC 1234
CSC 003E
CSC AAF8
etc.
```

I need to find the first code that has numerical values only.

I'm using the following sentence:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Customer 
WHERE custcode LIKE 'CSC [1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]' 
ORDER BY custcode;
```

But it gives 0 results. What is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

[`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) is for wildcards, not regexes.

<sup>This is really clear in the documentation — why are you not reading it?!</sup>

---

Perhaps you're after [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM Customer 
 WHERE custcode REGEXP 'CSC [1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]'
 ORDER BY custcode;
```

Also, I think you mean `LIMIT 1` with MySQL (`TOP 1` is from Microsoft SQL Server), and we can condense that regex:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Customer 
 WHERE custcode REGEXP 'CSC [1-9]{4}'
 ORDER BY custcode
 LIMIT 1;
```

---

**Update** *sllev* makes a very good point that you might mean `[0-9]` rather than `[1-9]`. Adapt appropriately.

---

<sup>(And it's "query", not "sentence".)</sup>

Comment: @sllev: Because that is the stated requirement.

Comment: @sllev: Well, OK, it's not the stated requirement but it's part of the original approach, so I'll assume that to be a not-broken part of the original implementation. The OP can easily change it if he decides to alter his regex logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer  
WHERE custcode REGEXP 'CSC [[:digit:]]{4}'; 
ORDER BY custcode
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yep I miswsed that each entry has CSCS at the beginning, I've udpated pattern but can not test it right now

Comment: `TOP` is not a MySQL keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Never having been one to shy away from spoon-feeding...

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer 
WHERE custcode REGEXP 'CSC [1-9]{4}' 
ORDER BY custcode;
```

Answer (score -1):

or without regex:

SELECT *
FROM Customer 
WHERE custcode >= 'CSC 0000' AND custcode <= 'CSC 9999'
ORDER BY custcode
LIMIT 1;

Also, will use the index of custcode(if is defined) for filtering.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the specs..  than:SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE custcode <= 'CSC 9999' ORDER BY custcode LIMIT 1;

Comment: Also no. What is that supposed to do? You haven't verified that the second token is all numeric, and your comparison evaluates to `true` for _all sorts of things_ that don't start with `'CSC '`. Look up how lexical (string) comparisons work.

Comment: Ok, than specify clear the problem ... In your specs all starts with "CSC ".

Comment: the last version: SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE custcode >= 'CSC 0000' AND custcode <= 'CSC 9999' ORDER BY custcode LIMIT 1;

Comment: It's not "my" spec, and the problem is very clearly stated: no other responders have had trouble with it.